# Insert two select queries in a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two select statements, both having some common fields.

This is my table structure :

```
Id, year, valueA, ValueB
```

Here is my two select statements

```
SELECT 
    id, [year],
    SUM(Total_Volume) / (count(distinct(month)) * 7) 
FROM
    TableA  
GROUP BY
    id, [year]
```

and

```
SELECT
    id, [year],
    SUM(Total_volume) / (count(distinct(month)) * 5)
FROM
    TableA  
WHERE 
    weekday NOT IN ('Friday','Saturday') 
GROUP BY 
    station_id, [year]
```

I have two different conditions for two statements. `Id` and `year` is common for both the statements.

Result from  first select statement should be stored in column `valueA` and result from second select statement should be stored in `ValueB` .

Any possible way to combine these queries and insert them into table as a single statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.id ,a.[year],valA,valB
from(
SELECT id ,[year],SUM(Total_Volume)/ (count(distinct(month))*7) valA from TableA  
group by id,[year]) a INNER JOIN

(select id,[year],SUM(Total_volume)/(count(distinct(month))*5) valB
from TableA  
WHERE weekday NOT IN ('Friday','Saturday') 
group by station_id,[year]) b
on a.id=b.id and a.[year]=b.[year]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do both the calculation in a single query

```
SELECT id, 
   [year], 
   Sum(total_volume) / ( Count(DISTINCT( Month)) * 7 ), 
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN weekday NOT IN ('Friday', 'Saturday' ) THEN 
         total_volume 
         ELSE 0 
       END) / (Count(DISTINCT( Month)) * 5 ) 
FROM   tableA 
GROUP  BY id, 
      [year];
```